# Making Database for wordNet in SICStus

Tags: prolog, nlp

I would like to make a prolog database that holds every synsets in wordNet which are about 117.000 synsets. As wordNet actually is kind of multi trees; some daughters have many parents, so I would like to know the highest level of synsets and record in front of it for example:

```
(100003993, 0, 45716).
(100005787, 0, 38923).
(100005930, 0, 42017).
(100006024, 0, 23002).
(100006150, 0, 09839).
```

And so on,….

What does these numbers mean?
The first argument in the first line which is 100003993 is the synset ID, the second is telling how many parents this synset has and because it is the lights level it has no parents at all so we record 0. The last argument is telling how many daughters this synset has and because it is one of the most top items in the tree, so they will be a lot for example what I have written here randomly which is 45716. In the most bottom leaves the code will be something like (10000174, 54034, 0) and that means there are 54034 parent synsets and 0 daughter synsets. I wish to record these information for every synset in wordNet and keep them in a database.

Comment: Are you aware that WordNet has official Prolog version?